# Сумма значений в колонке

Tags: android, sqlite

Имеется android приложение. В базу данных вносятся разные цифры. Как сделать так, чтобы в TextView отображалась сумма всех значений в колонке?

Comment: Покажите свои наработки, как Вы пытались сделать эту задачу.

Comment: Нет наработок. Знаю что в SQLite это делается командой SELECT SUM (имя_колонки) FROM имя_таблицы а как это припилить к андроиду - никак не пойму(